# websocket ping with node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

I am learning on how to use websockets. I am returning data to the front-end from the server via normal `ws.send` but I would at the same time I would like to have a set interval time to ping the front-end to see if clints are still alive there.. This is the code I am using at the moment.

```
ws.on('connection', function connection(ws, req) {

  ws.on('message', function incoming(message) {
    return_data = message;
    heart_beat = {status:"Accepted", currentTime:"2013-02-01T20:53:32.486Z", "heartbeatInterval":300}

    ws.send(JSON.stringify(heart_beat));
    const interval = setInterval(function ping() {
    ws.clients.forEach(function each(ws) {
      if (ws.isAlive === false) return ws.terminate();

        ws.isAlive = false;
        ws.ping('', false, true);
      });
  }, 300);
  });
});
```

I want to just wait 300 seconds, if there is no response from the front-end I will terminate the websocket after the first heartbeat send by me

Here is my front-end code.

```
ws.onopen = function(){
    console.log("Connected");
}
ws.onclose = function(){
    console.log("Disconnected");
    ws.send('Disconnected');
}
```

Whats happening now is that, when I close the browser in the front-end the server in the back-end is still pinging, if I console.log it.

Comment: What do you mean by `client are still alive` ?

Comment: @BrahmaDev Client ( in the browser ) - if they close the browser they are gone, thats what I meant.

Comment: If they close the browser, the websocket connection is gone too. You should no longer find them in `ws.clients`.

Comment: @BrahmaDev Not always, I want to use ping  messages  as a means to verify that the remote endpoint is still responsive. Even in the websocket repo in github they said it and I copied this example from there as well

Comment: Can you please point me to that. This is new to me.

Comment: https://github.com/websockets/ws 
( How to detect close broken connection ) if you scroll a bit down you will see it.

Comment: I see. Sorry I had a different module in mind.

Comment: The issue with your code is that you're calling the setInterval multiple times. The `setInterval` has to be outside the connection. Also you're using the same variable name multiple times, which is probably adding to confusion. Go through their example once again.

Comment: @BrahmaDev Yea the naming convention is bad, but yea I saw their example as well, and I put it outside but it was not doing anything when I turned off the browser from the client side

Comment: That's expected. `Sometimes the link between the server and the client can be interrupted in a way that keeps both the server and the client unaware of the broken state of the connection (e.g. when pulling the cord).` Other modules have an internal timeout to do this automatically, while `ws` seems to have chosen to offload this on to the developer.

Comment: But thats the reason why ping and heartbeat is being used, so it should have terminatted from my node js server which din't :(

Comment: No. In most cases `ws` will know that the client has disconnected. So that client won't exist in `ws.clients`. You have to recreate a bad connection to make that ping/pong timeout.

Comment: Just copying their example should be enough. You don't need to make any big changes to it. If you really want to test it, do what they suggest. Run it on a server, connect from a browser and then disconnect the lan cable.

Comment: okay, but the last question is that, how can I send the heartbeat object in the ping - thats what I really want

Comment: That's the first parameter of `ws.ping`

Answer (score 3):

You have to clear the Timeout with **[clearInterval](https://nodejs.org/api/timers.html#timers_clearinterval_timeout)**

Here is a working example with uWebSocket :

```
'use strict';

const uws = require('uws');

const PORT = 3000


/*********************************************************************
*                               Server                               *
*********************************************************************/

var wsServer = new uws.Server({ 'port': PORT });

let nextId=1;

wsServer.on('connection', function(ws) {
    console.log('connection !');

    ws.id='cnx'+nextId++;

    ws.on('message', function(mess){console.log('message : '+mess); });

    ws.on('error', function(error) {
        console.log('Cannot start server');
    });

    ws.on('close', function(code, message) {
            console.log('Disconnection: ' + code + ', ' + message);
            clearInterval(ws.timer);
            });

    ws.on('pong',function(mess) { console.log(ws.id+' receive a pong : '+mess); });

    ws.timer=setInterval(function(){pingpong(ws);},1000);

});

function pingpong(ws) {
    console.log(ws.id+' send a ping');
    ws.ping('coucou',{},true);
} // end of pingpong


/*********************************************************************
*                               Client                               *
*********************************************************************/

var wsClient1 = createClient('client1');
var wsClient2 = createClient('client2');

function createClient(id) {
    var client = new uws('ws://localhost:'+PORT);
    client.id=id;
    client.on('ping',function(mess){ console.log(this.id+' receive a ping : '+mess); } );
    client.on('message',function(mess){ console.log(this.id+' receive a message : '+mess); } );
    client.on('close',function(){ console.log(this.id+' closed'); } );
    return client;
}

function closeClient(client) {
    console.log('close '+client.id); client.close();
}

setTimeout(function(){ closeClient(wsClient1); closeClient(wsClient2); wsServer.close(); },2500);
```

output is :

```
connection !
connection !
cnx1 send a ping
cnx2 send a ping
client2 receive a ping : coucou
client1 receive a ping : coucou
cnx1 receive a pong : coucou
cnx2 receive a pong : coucou
cnx1 send a ping
cnx2 send a ping
client2 receive a ping : coucou
client1 receive a ping : coucou
cnx1 receive a pong : coucou
cnx2 receive a pong : coucou
close client1
close client2
client1 closed
client2 closed
Disconnection: 0,
Disconnection: 0,
```